# Different time sysdate and current_date when connect to database since application server

Tags: oracle

I have a problem with the time that Oracle gives me when working with applications.

I currently connect from an application server (apx1) to a server containing Oracle 19c (bdx1) for database operations.

Both the application server and the database server are in the Canary Islands, so it must show/work local time there (GMT +1 in summer, GMT in winter).

If I launch the date command on the servers, the time appears correct.

```bash
[oracle@apx1 oracle]$ date
vie jul  1 14:25:49 BST 2022
```

```bash
[oracle@bdx1 ~]$ date
vie jul  1 14:25:46 BST 2022
```

However, after making the connection from apx1 to bdx1, I get this time offset:

```sql
SQL> select systimestamp, current_timestamp, localtimestamp from dual;
SYSTIMESTAMP
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
LOCALTIMESTAMP
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
01/07/22 15:27:39,762772 +02:00
01/07/22 14:27:39,762775 +01:00
01/07/22 14:27:39,762775
```

I don't know what I should configure to correct this offset.

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72830073/different-time-sysdate-and-current-date-when-connect-to-database-since-applicati/72830389

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the time on the server itself seems to be correct, it looks however you start the database overrides this setting. This is typically caused by the `TZ` environment variable.

Make sure you start the database from a session/script that uses the correct `TZ` value.

If you start the database manually or from a script, check if `TZ` is set anywhere. If yes, change it to the correct value:

```
export TZ=Atlantic/Canary
```

If the database is started through Grid Infrastructure, check if the environment variable was set:

```
srvctl getenv database -db DBNAME
grep ^TZ ${GRID_HOME}/crs/install/s_crsconfig_$(hostname)_env.txt
```

If it needs to be changed, change as:

```
srvctl setenv database -db DBNAME -env "TZ=Atlantic/Canary"
```

Or edit the above text file.

After changing the GI env file, a GI restart is needed for the changes to take effect. For the other changes, a DB restart is enough.

Comment: I have changed the parameter, but the query still gives me the wrong time in SYSTIMESTAMP.

```sql
[oracle@bdx1 install]$ srvctl getenv database -db DDBB
DDBB:
TZ=Atlantic/Canary
```

Comment: Finally, this change is the right one. But it is not enough to restart the cluster, the host must also be restarted. Thank you very much!